# How to render the svg string from fabric.js in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

For example, I added a circle on the fabric.Canvas.

For this circle, the `toJSON()` gives me the following info:

```
{
      type: 'circle',
      version: '4.6.0',
      originX: 'left',
      originY: 'top',
      left: 241.21,
      top: 141.63,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      fill: 'blue',
      stroke: null,
      strokeWidth: 0,
      strokeDashArray: null,
      strokeLineCap: 'butt',
      strokeDashOffset: 0,
      strokeLineJoin: 'miter',
      strokeUniform: false,
      strokeMiterLimit: 4,
      scaleX: 1,
      scaleY: 1,
      angle: 0,
      flipX: false,
      flipY: false,
      opacity: 1,
      shadow: null,
      visible: true,
      backgroundColor: '',
      fillRule: 'nonzero',
      paintFirst: 'fill',
      globalCompositeOperation: 'source-over',
      skewX: 0,
      skewY: 0,
      radius: 50,
      startAngle: 0,
      endAngle: 6.283185307179586,
      id: 'CanvasCircle:01FFY0FCHMX0HV285Q85E3C23A'
}
```

The `toSVG()` gives a SVG string like this:

`'<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 291.21 191.63)" id="CanvasCircle:01FFY0FCHMX0HV285Q85E3C23A"  >\n<circle style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"  cx="0" cy="0" r="50" />\n</g>\n'`

My question is how to render this SVG string as a SVG in React.js?

I am doing something like this, the height and width is the params for this canvas circle:

```
   <div
      style={{
        height,
        width,
        zIndex: 11,
      }}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html:`<svg width="${width}px" height="${height}px" viewBox="0 0 ${width} ${height}" >${svgString}</svg>`,
      }}
    />
```

It renders like this in the HTML

```
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; z-index: 11;"><svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 351.53 205.4)" id="CanvasCircle:01FFY1BD3EQW39JGWJ0AWQ2R1B">
```

Which does not show anything on the page, seems the `cx` and `cy` are wrong? So they should be `50`, changing this to 50 indeed gives me the SVG?

However, I ended up solving it by rendering the SVG on my own, it works now,

Still wonder what is the `fabric.js` way of doing it, or this `toSVG()` suppose to be broken? What am I missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the group ( the circle ) is transformed with a translation, probably because in the canvas is somewhere in the middle.

If you want to have the circle display in a square as big as the circle itself, change its left and top to 0 and 0 before exporting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need that top and left value in order to render them in a relative position later in a div element.